# Gradle project sync failure in android studio 1.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an error i.e. error(5,0) Invalid revision:22.0.c3 when i do `Gradle` project sync and it fails by showing this message what should i do now I have android studio 1.2.2

Comment: why are you still using Android Studio 1.2.2? Get 2.1 and make life simpler.

Comment: what is in your gradle file, also this is several versions old.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to fix something in an outdated version. Upgrade your Android studio to the latest version. 2.1 as of today.

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of android studio tend to have problems with gradle sync/build. You should upgrade your `Android studio` to `v2.1` and try again. The problem you are facing will most probable eliminate after the upgrade.